# CWAC-CAM2 confirm image is coarse

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Confirm screen show image as coarse.

I tested it with Pantech IM model -version is kitkat.

How can I display confirmation image as more smoothly?

[coarse image at confirm screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLsV1.png)

```
Intent i=new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(getActivity())
        .facing(CameraActivity.Facing.BACK)
        .to(new File(tmpCameraPic))
        .debug()
        .updateMediaStore()
        .build();

startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

Comment: "Confirm screen show image as coarse." - I have no idea what this means, sorry.

Comment: If do not use 'skipConfirm()', cwac show confirm screen.  But at this time, shown image is very coarse.  If I check image at gallery, it shows smooth image.  I think android do it when display image to view.  Can I manually use this point i.q. picasso library?

Comment: "shown image is very coarse" -- I have no idea what this means, sorry. "Can I manually use this point i.q. picasso library?" -- I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving some heap to the preview so cam2 can load the image with a better quality.

From [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/docs/CameraActivity.md) documentation page, add the confirmationQuality(0.1f) to the intent. 0.1f -> Better quality.

```
Intent i=new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(getActivity())
        .facing(CameraActivity.Facing.BACK)
        .to(new File(tmpCameraPic))
        .debug()
        .updateMediaStore()
        .confirmationQuality(0.1f)
        .build();
```